# Measure and limit file uploads

Tags: plugins, uploads

I want to deliver WordPress powered packages to some users and want them to have:

1. a limitation on disk quota (/each user)
2. A way to measure/show how many MBs they are currently using

Any solution would be appreciated

Comment: You'll probably get some better answers if you describe your use case in a bit more detail.  Eg. what will these users be able to do other than upload files? Do they need their own "site"?

Comment: @ChristopherDavis: You are right, users would be able to add/edit posts. There's no need for them to have their "own site".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a multi site installation for this.  Give each user their own blog.

Multi Site has built in disk quota functionality, and you can see how much of it is used and such in the admin area of each site.  You can set the quota in the network admin: `settings > network settings`.

Combine that with domain mapping allowing your users to have their own domains and you've got a fairly powerful system.